# RuntimeError: Given normalized_shape=[256], expected input with shape [*, 256], but got input of size[640, 256, 14, 14]

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, object-detection

I get this error when I use `nn.LayerNorm` and I do not know how to fix it. This is some tracing that I did for my layers to show you the parameters:

```
Sequential(
(0): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), groups=256)
)
Sequential(
(0): sMLPBlock(
(proj_h): Linear(in_features=14, out_features=14, bias=True)
(proj_w): Linear(in_features=14, out_features=14, bias=True)
(fuse): Conv2d(768, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
)
)
Sequential(
(0): Linear(in_features=256, out_features=512, bias=True)
(1): GELU()
(2): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
(3): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=256, bias=True)
(4): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
)
```

Can you help me fix this problem please?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: After sMLP, [the paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-022-20440-z) use `reshape` to flatten the input (see fig 1, and [pytorch's flatten](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Flatten.html)). But before that I'm not sure if sMLP is implemented correctly (see fig 2, need to debug further). Also adding dropout as the final layer is a bit odd

Comment: After flatten the vector it would become `[640, 50176]`. If that is too large, try add pooling layer, or stack a bunch of `Conv2d` such that the output size become `[640, 256, 1, 1]` before flattening